# Add median in st() of vtable

Tags: r, vtable

How can I add the median stat in `st()` function of `vtable` package?

```
library(vtable)
st(iris)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (the median will be under the heading Pctl. 50)
The default parameter is set to false when you check `?st`

```
st(iris, add.median = TRUE)
```

Comment: Can I rename it?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure since I'm unfamiliar with the package. It seems the `labels` package doesn't rename columns unfortuantely. There might be a way using other kable packages though.

Comment: You can rename the columns using the `summ.names` option.